# Strange number theory proof, help requested

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $F_{n}=2^{2^{n}}+1$. Prove that $\prod_{0\leq k<n}F_{k}=F_{n}-2$, and hence that $(F_{m},F_{n})=1$ for $m\neq n$

As far as I understand, I need to use induction on $n$ to prove the equality part. If I understand correctly, then my base case goes as follows:

$$LHS: 2^{2^{0}}+1=2+1=3.\text{  } RHS: 2^{2^{1}}-1=4-1=3$$

But I don't understand how to show the fact that $(F_m,5)=1$ for the base, and subsequent inductive steps...

Comment: $F_0=2^{2^0}+1=3$, and $(3,5)=1$.  What happens when you multiply $F_0\cdot F_1\cdot F_2$ and simplify?

Comment: But this just shows that $(3,5)=1$... but I need to show that every $(F_m,5)=1$ except where $F_m=F_n$.

Comment: Suppose you have the product identity proved. Then you know, for $m < n$, that $F_m \mid (F_n - 2)$, hence $(F_m, F_n) = (F_m, F_n - (F_n-2)) = (F_m,2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the induction step, note that
$$F_{n+1}-2=2^{2^{n+1}}-1=(2^{2^n}-1)(2^{2^n}+1)=(F_n-2) F_n.\tag{1}$$
The factorization  $2^{2^{n+1}}-1=(2^{2^n}-1)(2^{2^n}+1)$ comes from the fact that $2^{2^{n+1}}=2^{2\cdot 2^n}=(2^{2^n})^2$.

Using (1) and the induction hypothesis, we have
$$F_{n+1}-2=(F_n-2)F_n=\left(\prod_{k\lt n}F_k\right)F_n=\prod_{k\lt n+1}F_k.$$ 
This completes the proof of the induction step.

For the relative primality result, use the identity 
$$F_n-2=\prod_{k\lt n}F_k$$
to show that if $m\lt n$ then any divisor of $F_m$ and $F_n$ divides both $F_{n}-2$ and $F_n$, so it divides $2$. But if $n\gt 0$, then $F_n$ is odd.